# Android lock orientation to starting orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I've searched for a long time but nothing works.I have an activity and I want its orientation locked while activity's whole lifecycle.This orientation must be starting orientation.I mean, when activity starts on any orientation , it must ignore orientation changes.How Can I do this ?
Thanks for replies..

Answer (score 3):

By code you can request for an orientation for your activity 'onCreate' call like this :

```
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

and you can read the current orientation like this :

```
   getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

So you can read the current orientation and request it to stay the same with :

```
   int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
   setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
```

You also may want to disable activity lifecycle events from the orientation change by adding configChanges:orientation in your manifest :

```
   <activity android:name="MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation">
       ...
   </activity>
```

Comment: not working :( Actually , I want to prevent restarting of activity because of screen orientation change but it try to restart the activity when I rotate the screen

Comment: Check your manifest, the android:configChanges="orientation" is here to prevent the activity from restarting like you describe :/  it should work...

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is :
Override `onConfigurationChanged()` like this [How to use onConfigurationChanged() and newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE in android 2.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566633/how-to-use-onconfigurationchanged-and-newconfig-orientation-configuration-o)

but do not call `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)`

Comment: I dd it.My onConfigurationChanged method is completely empty but unfortunately , it try to restart the activity for ne orientation when I rotate screen :( I want to prevent that

Comment: I mean activity must hold on , not should restart

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the activity's section in the manifest file. This will tell Android that you want to handle orientation changes yourself.

Then implement the [`onConfigurationChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) method of your activity and handle the change at will. In your case you'd probably simply do nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately , it try to restart the activity :( I want to prevent that

Comment: Have you added the android:configChanges="orientation" line? This should prevent Android from restarting the Activity in case of change of orientation and instead invoke onConfigurationChanged(). Can you check if onConfigurationChanged() is called at all?

Comment: Yes in my activity tag , android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" is written.And in my acitivity class there is a method like this : @Override 
public void onConfigurationChanged(){ //empty }

Answer (score -1):

Add this below line in your manifest under each activity

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```