# How is orientation change handled in the message queue?

Tags: android

Is it an atomic operation?

I mean is it possible that anything else gets executed on the main thread during an orientation change?

For example, let's say the flow on the main thread is something like this:

*someOperation -> **orientationChangeStart** -> someOtherOperation -> **orientationChangeEnd***

Is this possible?

Can `someOtherOperation` get executed on the UI thread while an orientation change is in progress?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is atomic operation.

in pseudo it looks like:

```
void setNewOrientation(int state) {
    currentState = state;
    runOrientationChangedEvent();
}
```

And then usually `Activity` is re-created. Only re-creating of Activity adds to the message queue, so it is possible to see if change device orientation fast enough.

You cannot get start and end of this process, because it just changes a few int variables which can tell you about current orientation like **orientation**:

```
getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

or **rotation**

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

So you can get event only **after** orientation is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you will not be able to measure time between **orientationChangeStart** and **orientationChangeEnd** but you can execute your *someOtherOperation* handling **onConfigurationChanged** event.
Example:
[How to use onConfigurationChanged() and newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE in android 2.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566633/how-to-use-onconfigurationchanged-and-newconfig-orientation-configuration-o)

Comment: that is not an operation **while** it changes. Its only **after** it changed.